# How to detach Outline from Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Problem**: Detaching the Outline section from Explorer and moving it to the right side.

**Tried**: right-clicking, changing the settings - cannot find where and how the Outline section be detached from Explorer.

**Question**: is it possible to detach the Outline Panel from Explorer Panel? 
Is there another extension, which the same functionality as Outline, which could be placed on the right side?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This should be supported directly in VSCode 1.64 (Jan. 2022), with the new side panel.

> ### [New Side Panel](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/69ecc3b82e334196beedf4b31dc89f7ba754badf/release-notes/v1_64.md#new-side-panel)
>
> This milestone, we introduce the Side Panel, a new surface in the workbench to house views from the Side Bar or the bottom Panel appearing opposite the Side Bar.
>
> Unlike the historical ability to move the bottom Panel to the left or the right of the editor, the new Side Panel works in addition to the bottom Panel so you can see more sets of views at once.
>
> To use the Side Panel, you'll need to move some views over to it.
>
> Based on one of our most upvoted feature requests, you might want to move Outline from the Side Bar to Side Panel.
> You can do this by dragging and dropping the view into the Side Panel.
>
> If the Side Panel is not open, just like the bottom Panel, dragging a view to the edge of the editor area, will pop it open.
> Alternatively, you can use the Move View command for something more keyboard friendly.
>
> Moving Outline View to the Side Panel:
>
> [image: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/raw/vnext/release-notes/images/1_64/sidepanel_outline.gif]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, click on the Outline Title Bar and you can move it to any other panel, even the bottom Problems/Terminal panel.

You don't need any special extension for it. Almost all panels can be moved around in VSCode

You cannot have a **Floating Window** however.

You also Cannot have **Two Sidebars**

If you want to have the sidebar to the right go to `View - Appearance - Move Side Bar Right`

[image: result]

As of now, no you cannot have two sidebars, [this is the issue tracking](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26777) that feature.

I can suggest an alternative, you can move the outline to the bottom panel, where the terminal is so that you can have both at the same time but just not as a sidebar.

like this:

[image: outline bottom]

or like this but attaching two Bottom Panel tabs together.

[image: terminal outline]

[Here is a Demo on how to do it](https://i.imgur.com/wzOBkBT.gifv)

Comment: OK, but is it possible to have both the Explorer and Outline views simultaneously but on the opposite sides? E.g. Explorer on the Left side, the Outliner on the Right Side while leaving the Terminal Bar sit on the bottom?

Comment: As of now, no you cannot have two sidebars, [this is the issue tracking that feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26777). I can suggest an alternative, you can move the outline to the bottom panel, where the terminal is so that you can have both at the same time but just not as a sidebar. like this https://i.imgur.com/IfpGepe.png or like this https://i.imgur.com/MQKr3Mo.png

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of searching, I finally came up with my own solution. Apologies in advance for the poor screenshot quality. I used Microsoft's Steps Recording not realizing the image compression would be so poor.

First, open up a new terminal (Ctrl+Shift+`)
[image: Default panel locations]

Make sure that the terminal tab is active in the panel. Right click the terminal name on the right-hand side and select "Move into editor area.

[image: Move terminal into editor area.]"

You can then right-click the now-tabbed Terminal in your editor space and select "Split down." [image: Split terminal down]

Your editor should look like the image below. However, we're not done yet! Here's where the magic happens. Open another terminal.
[image: Almost there... open another terminal now]

Things will look weird but this is going to work.
Click the "Outline" header in the sidebar and drag it into the bottom terminal panel:
[image: Click and drag the outline section of the sidebar]

Sidebar > (Outline) > Terminal Panel

[image: Make sure to drop it in the terminal!]

Next, right-click on the tab bar of the bottom panel and select "Move Panel Right"[image: Right click and select "Move Panel Right"]

*Et voila!* You should how have a sidebar on the left, and Outline on the right, and a Terminal on the bottom!

[image: You're done!]

Comment: Unfortunately all tabs like Problems, Debug console etc. are moved to the right, too.

Comment: I don't think there is a perfect solution, unfortunately.